# Emacs (-nw) version 24.4.1 adds escape code to the top of every file, when 24.3.1 doesn't

Tags: terminal-emacs

When I run 'emacs -nw --no-init abc' with emacs version 24.4.1, I always see the same escape codes inserted at the top of the file:  "12;rgb:0000/0000/0000".  When I run the same command on the same machine with emacs version 24.3.1 I don't see those escape codes. Has something changed that I need to adapt to or is this an emacs bug?  This is on RedHat 5.8.  TERM is set to xterm.

Both versions were installed by recompiling from source.  This also happens with emacs version 24.5.1.

Comment: Weird. How did you install Emacs? Does this same behaviour show up when you start from different terminal emulators (xterm, gnome-terminal etc) or the console?

Comment: It appears to have been a known bug, but I can't figure out if it's been fixed and in which versions:  http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=12354

Comment: It's fixed in the version I'm running: 24.5.50.2